# Can someone show me an example rootstock smart contract that is the equivalent of an Ethereum Smart Contract?

Tags: ethereum, rootstock

Coming from Ethereum, is there an example rootstock smart contract code that is the equivalent of an Ethereum smart contract code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you are a solidity developer you can write any contract using solidity and compile it and publish it directly to the RSK Smart network using the RSK [Console](https://github.com/RSKsmart/rskj/wiki/RSK-Console) or alternatively using RPC calls like :

```
curl -X POST --data '
{
    "jsonrpc" : "2.0",
    "method" : "eth_sendTransaction",
    "params" : [{
            "from" : "0x9e54691b45abfe4552cb03a8247a8da8a3c43d32",
            "data" : "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"
        }
    ],
    "id" : 1
}’ http://<RSKNode>:<RSKNodePort>
```

the bytecode could be get from solidity browser or using solc.

**Edit**:  you can configure [Remix](https://remix.ethereum.org) or truffle to connect to the RSK node and deploy directy your smart contract